# Tsung is started failed

Tags: erlang, tsung

I used 
Ejabberd version ：15.10 
Erlang/OTP version： 18
Tsung version： 1.6.1

when i starting tsung after "make install", use:

> xxxxx:~/.tsung$ tsung -f jabber_register.xml start

eg:the jabber_register.xml is copyed from example

then show that:

```
Starting Tsung 
Log directory is: /home/user/.tsung/log/20151112-1105 
[os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed  
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed
```

What causes the failure？

Comment: You should find more information in the logs.

Comment: =ERROR REPORT==
** Generic server ts_config_server terminating 
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',{newbeams,[localhost]}}
** When Server state == ...

** Reason for termination == 
** {function_clause,
       [{lists,min,[[]],[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,314}]},
        {ts_config_server,handle_cast,2,
            [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_config_server.erl"},{line,383}]},
        {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,615}]},
        {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,681}]},
        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}

Comment: and then:  
=ERROR REPORT==== 12-Nov-2015::15:33:34 ===
** State machine ts_launcher terminating 
** Last event in was {launch,[],"localhost",now}
** When State == wait
**      Data  == {launcher,undefined,[],"ubuntu",undefined,false,0,undefined,
                           undefined,undefined,1,undefined,1,undefined}

Comment: and then:
** Reason for termination = 
** {{function_clause,
        [{lists,min,[[]],[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,314}]},
         {ts_config_server,handle_cast,2,
             [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_config_server.erl"},{line,383}]},
         {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,615}]},
         {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,681}]},
         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]},
    {gen_server,call,
        [{global,ts_config_server},{get_client_config,"localhost"},60000]}}

Comment: the above parts of log info is usable?

Comment: tsung is not easy to run. It runs based on its configuration file. Most error from the wrong configuration. I ran it and debug the configuration error through the source code.

Comment: I reinstall erlang and tsung by more low version and run ok： otp 17.4 and   tsung 1.6.1，at the same time run at new VM。

Answer (score 1):

I use riak recently, and encountered similar problem.

This is the full console info of starting riak:

```
config is OK
-config /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/app.2015.12.02.16.53.53.config -args_file /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2015.12.02.16.53.53.args -vm_args /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2015.12.02.16.53.53.args
Exec:  /usr/lib64/riak/erts-5.10.3/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib64/riak/releases/2.0.4/riak               -config /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/app.2015.12.02.16.53.53.config -args_file /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2015.12.02.16.53.53.args -vm_args /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2015.12.02.16.53.53.args -pa /usr/lib64/riak/lib/basho-patches -- console
Root: /usr/lib64/riak
Erlang R16B02_basho6 (erts-5.10.3) [source-bcd8abb] [64-bit] [smp:1:1] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true] [frame-pointer]

[os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller," {application_start_failure,riak_core,{invalid_ring_state_dir,{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: /var/log/riak/erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,riak_core,{invalid_ring_state_dir,{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

I discovered some resource on riak official sites, and understand the problem.

> Riak's Erlang VM is built with SMP support and if Riak is started on a non-SMP system, an error like this one is logged. This is commonly seen in virtualized environments configured for only one CPU core.

I assumed you run Tsung in VM either.

Enjoy!

**Reference:**

- [Common Errors](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/recovery/errors/)

Comment: I am experiencing the same error. I am working in a virtualized environment configured for one CPU core.How did you over come it?